# Is it possible to specify what index a query should use in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

MongoDB seems like it is using an inefficient query pattern when one index is a subset of another index.

```
class Model
  field :status, :type => Integer
  field :title, :type => String
  field :subtitle, :type => String
  field :rating, :type => Float

  index([
    [:status, Mongo::ASCENDING],
    [:title, Mongo::ASCENDING],
    [:subtitle, Mongo::ASCENDING],
    [:rating, Mongo::DESCENDING]
  ])
  index([
    [:status, Mongo::ASCENDING],
    [:title, Mongo::ASCENDING],
    [:rating, Mongo::DESCENDING]
  ])
end
```

The first index is being used both when querying on `status`, `title` and `subtitle` and sorting on `rating` and when querying on just `status` and `title` and sorting on `rating` even though using `explain()` along with `hint()` in the javascript console states that using the second index is 4 times faster.

How can I tell Mongoid to tell MongoDB to use the second index?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass options such as hint to `Mongo::Collection` using `Mongoid::Criterion::Optional.extras`

An example:

```
criteria = Model.where(:status => true, :title => 'hello world').desc(:rating)
criteria.extras(:hint => {:status => 1, :title => 1, :rating => -1})
```

`extras` accepts anything that [Mongo::Collection](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/master/Mongo/Collection) can handle

Comment: Hm, interesting. As far as I know mongodb could use only one index. So it's a little bit confusing why you put hash to your hint value

Comment: The hash hint value there corresponds to the [[:status, Mongo::ASCENDING],[:title, Mongo::ASCENDING],[:rating, Mongo::DESCENDING]] index, so it is still only using a single index

Comment: so it's compaund index? from status, title and rating. Ok, then I see.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimization#Optimization-Hint

> While the mongo query optimizer often
>   performs very well, explicit "hints"
>   can be used to force mongo to use a
>   specified index, potentially improving
>   performance in some situations.

`db.collection.find({user:u, foo:d}).hint({user:1});`

You need to work from http://www.rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Cursor here as I do not know Ruby enough. It mentions hint.

Comment: I'm not sure Mongoid::Cursor is the correct path.  It delegates hint to Mongo::Cursor where hint is a readonly attribute.